# How to handle situation where page unloads due to low memory

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

```
//In App Delegate
UserProfileTableViewController *uptvc = [[UserProfileTableViewController alloc]init];
UITabBarItem *tempTabBarItem4 = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Fans" image:nil tag:FANSTAB_INDEX];

//I am setting the user id information here directly in app delegate
uptvc.userId = [[UserStockInfo sharedUserStockInfo]getUserId];
UINavigationController *navconUptvc = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:uptvc];
```

The problem arises when my UserProfileTableViewController gets unloaded due to low memory (might be due to using the camera feature in my app). The page will fail to load properly as it is missing the 'userId' information passed in from the app delegate (as seen above). I am unable to set this userId information directly in the UserProfileTableViewController (in view did load method) as other pages might pass a different userId when pushing the page onto their stack.

Any advise on how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: your view is unloaded not dealloc'd so your userID should not be lost unless you are setting it to nil in your `viewDidUnLoad` method, in which case you should simply not set it to nil.

Comment: Can we see your `viewDidUnload` method? You should only release/set to nil anything that ws created in `viewDidLoad` think of the two methods as a matched pair. I get the feeling you are setting id to nil at some point like @rog said

Comment: Paul.s I think you are right about that. I am actually setting more than what I have in view did load to nil.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you should keep your UserProfileTableViewController object into an ivar of the app delegate (since you allocate it there). Second, make the app delegate provide that userId to the controller. Third, if the navigation controller is removed from the interface/deallocated, then even with low memory your uptvc should not be deallocated either.
View controllers maintain the full hierarchy of controllers, even when running out of memory, what's deleted are views, and anything you tell them to remove.

You most certainly want to keep the UINavigationController in an ivar of the AppDelegate as well.

Comment: 1. You do not need to keep `uptvc` in an ivar as it is not owned by the `appDelegate` it it owned by the `UINavigationController`. 2. This is already done in the third line. It may well be wise to keep an ivar to the `UINavigationController` for ease of access later. The problem was the id was being lost and simply having another pointer will not stop the `viewDidUnload` from being called